# Unit testing controllers using UserManager.FindById

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am new to unit testing .net applications and am having difficulty with what I would imagine to be a very simple case.

```
// GET: Entities
public ViewResult Index()
{
  _User = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  return View(entityRepository.GetEntities(_User.entityId));         
}
```

I want to test that the correct view is outputted but can't get past the user line. In other languages I would simply mock UserManager.FindById to always return some predefined object, but I can't get it to work.

Have been trying to follow the approach given here [example mocking the IUserStore](https://forums.asp.net/t/1993211.aspx?Mocking%20the%20IUserStore%20UserManager%20and%20MOQ)  but can't get it to work with my example. To mock FindByNameAsync they have used store.As

Any advice would be gratefully received.

My attempt was to follow a similar method to that in link above. Obviously IUserPasswordStore is the wrong interface, but I am not sure how to find the correct one.

```
 var store = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
 store.As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>()
      .Setup(x => x.FindById(It.IsAny<string>()))
      .Returns(ApplicationUser)null);   

 EntitiesController controller = new EntitiesController();
 var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
 Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
```

Comment: There is no way to answer the question without seeing your current attempts of mocking `UserManager`

Comment: Hi @haim770 Have edited above. I didn't include it originally because I don't think I was close to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass `store.Object` as an argument to the constructor of `EntitiesController` (which will then assign it to `this.UserManager`)?

Comment: @mwuk, I solved this by abstracting UserManager behind an interface I controlled and injected that as a dependency to my controller via constructor. the implementation class simply wrapped/adapted the actual UserManager class. That way I was able to mock implementation when unit testing

Comment: @mwuk the example you linked to has the answer. You need to follow that example. notice how they inject he user manager. if you are creating the manager locally then there is no way to inject a mock.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to the guidance from @Nkosi and @haim770 I think I have an answer. It still seems overly complex though, so would be interested to hear if you know how to simplify.

It started with needing to write more testable code, I installed Unity and started to inject dependencies allowing me to mock them out.

The solution that passes is:

```
Mock<IPrincipal> mockPrincipal;
string username = "test@test.com";

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    //Arrange                
    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "");
    var nameIdentifierClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username);
    identity.AddClaim(nameIdentifierClaim);

    mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identity);
    mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
}

[TestMethod]
public void EntitiesIndexDisplaysTheDefaultView()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(); 
    var principal = mockPrincipal.Object;
    context.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principal);

    var userManagerMock = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    userManagerMock.As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>()
         .Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(new ApplicationUser() { entityId = "id" });

    var entitiesRepositoryMock = new Mock<IEntityRepository>();
    entitiesRepositoryMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetEntities(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns((IEnumerable<Entity>)new List<Entity>());


    EntitiesController controller = new EntitiesController(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userManagerMock.Object), 
                                                               entitiesRepositoryMock.Object);

    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
    var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("", result.ViewName);           
}
```